# 502 Bad Gateway - connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, nginx

I have a VPS since many years. Everything was working fine.
The server was running PHP 7 and nginx.

Today the sites were running a bit slow. So I decided to login to the server and run a `shutdown -r now`.

After reboot I have `502 Bad Gateway` in the browser and `connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)` in the nginx error.log.

I have no idea what could went wrong during this reboot.
In `journalctl` I don't see any error on boot.

Mysql is starting well.

```
php -v
PHP 7.2.22

nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.12.2
```

Here are some parts I have in the vhosts:

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

Maybe I was running on PHP5 and on reboot it updated to PHP7?? Would that be possible?

In `yum history` the last install was in 2018.

```
ls -la |grep php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    4696240 Jul 20  2018 php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    4589728 Jul 20  2018 php-cgi
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root       4776 Jul 20  2018 phpize
```

This last says they are there since 2018, so I doubt a new php was installed after boot.
Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

P.s. I do not have a sites-enabled/ folder. The vhosts are in the `/etc/nginx/vhosts.d` folder.

I hope someone can help to troubleshoot and fix the issue

**EDIT:**
I don't know if it helps. I found out that in  `/var/run` I have only one folder `php-fpm` which is empty.
In my other 2 VPS with similar configuration (but are stil working) there are two items: `php7-fpm.sock` and the folder `php-fpm` which is not empty.

It's like PHP is not creating the sock there?

In `/etc/php-fpm.conf` I have `pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid`
In `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` I have `listen = /var/run/php7-fpm.sock`

**EDIT2:** 
I run `service php-fpm restart` and now it created the socks. And it's working.

**Final questions to answer this topic:**
I restarted many times in the last years the server and it was always fine. Today after rebooting there was this problem. I rebooted once again and still the same problem.
I had to manually restart php-fpm.

- Why I experienced this problem?
- What to do/check/fix in order to avoid this problem in future?

**EDIT3:**
It was working few days.
Today I decided to retry to reboot ubuntu.

After reboot, once again bad gateway.

```
[root@mysite ~]# ps faux|grep php
root     12149  0.0  0.0 112704   964 pts/0    S+   11:33   0:00                      \_ grep --color=auto php
```

Then I tried:

```
[root@mysite~]# systemctl enable php-fpm
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php-fpm.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.
```

Once again:

```
[root@www01 ~]# ps faux|grep php
root     12152  0.0  0.0 112704   964 pts/0    S+   11:37   0:00                      \_ grep --color=auto php
```

Then I tried:

```
[root@mysite~]# service php-fpm restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart php-fpm.service
[root@mysite~]# ps faux|grep php
root     12176  0.0  0.0 112704   960 pts/0    S+   11:38   0:00                      \_ grep --color=auto php
root     12169  4.5  1.5 473028 16000 ?        Ss   11:38   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
nginx    12170  0.0  0.7 473028  7668 ?        S    11:38   0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
nginx    12171  0.0  0.7 473028  7668 ?        S    11:38   0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
nginx    12172  0.0  0.7 473028  7668 ?        S    11:38   0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
nginx    12173  0.0  0.7 473028  7668 ?        S    11:38   0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
nginx    12174  0.0  0.7 473028  7672 ?        S    11:38   0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
```

But this time, even after `service php-fpm restart` and running php process, I get bad gateway :(

In journalctl I see:

```
Feb 18 11:45:47 mysitepolkitd[658]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12210:153462 (system bus name :1.19 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Feb 18 11:45:47 mysite systemd[1]: Stopping The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
Feb 18 11:45:47 mysite systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
Feb 18 11:45:47 mysite systemd[1]: Started The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
Feb 18 11:45:47 mysite polkitd[658]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12210:153462 (system bus name :1.19, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

Any idea?

Comment: did you try replacing php5 in the config with php7?

Comment: Yes, I replaced `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` with `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;` And now I get `*4889 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,`

Also I do confirm (I checked in the /etc/ backup) that also previously I was using `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` in all the vhosts.
Also I confirm I was running PHP7. I checked the configuration I sent to WPML for support tickets at all my sites were running on PHP7 and `php5-fpm.sock` in vhosts. So the problem is somewhere else

Comment: So check with `ps faux|grep php` whether a `php-fpm` process is running (if not someone need to start it ... your init system oder systemd or such) and check what files/sockets that process has open. You can see those under `ls -l /proc/$PID/fd` and use `ss` or `netstat -anp` or `lsof`. There you should see the socket you need to configure in the nginx config.

Comment: I added above an EDIT 3